# Как в в Java суммировать значения столбца в базе данных mySQL

Tags: java, mysql

Имеется база данных mySQL

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(На вопросительные знаки не обращайте внимание, не могу решить проблему кодировки, когда вводишь русские имена)
Нужно в Java посчитать и вывести в консоль сумму столбца money

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT SUM(money) FROM table_name");
```

Но как вывести в консоль, так не срабатывает

```
           ResultSet resultSet2 = statement.executeQuery("SELECT SUM(money) FROM table_name");
            int sum = resultSet2.getInt(3);
            System.out.println("Среднее" + sum);
```

Ошибка

```
java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int sum = 0;
if (resultSet2.next())
  sum = resultSet2.getInt(1);
```

---

`System.out.println("Среднее"...` - *"Если на клетке слона прочтешь надпись: буйвол, — не верь глазам своим." Козьмa Прутков*.

Comment: Спасибо, сработало, а почему нужно ставить "1"?

Comment: @Николай Потому что в Вашем `SELECT` только одно поле.